# Sound Showreel?

Tags: sound-design, portfolio, showreel

Whats the best way to display a showreel of sound related to the moving image - whats the best and how much information should you display for each separate piece of work and what is the optimum length??
I made this one recently but i dont think it has a great impact.... http://vimeo.com/24519080
Would you have any suggestions to make it more elaborate while still including the skill bases demonstrated?

Any help on this would be great,

Thanks, Gillian

Comment: I'd love to know this too, I haven't actually started on one yet because I'm afraid of putting something ineffective out there.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the following posts that discuss the subject of show reels. You'll probably find some interesting responses from the SSD community.

[Question discussing length of a show reel](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/3372/showreel-focusing-on-dialogue-editing-and-location-recording) including a fantastic response from Rene!

[Best way of presenting a show reel](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/224/whats-the-best-way-of-presenting-a-sound-design-showreel)

[What to put in a show reel](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/4823/what-to-put-in-show-reel)

Answer (score 1):

Hi Gillian. First of all, I really like your work! My tuppence worth is similar to Isra, be brutal on the editing to get it shorter (2/3 mins). Maybe just leave the more immediately 'wowing' stuff. Plenty in there. Cheers, N.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Gillian, maybe not trying to put everything there wolud be a nice start, curate your work and find key pieces and make a syntheis (2 min long could be a good reel). Findning a video editor or a motion graphic designer could help to improve your reel and make it look more attractive.
Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I might amend and add to this post later...

Some people say that you might want to have several videos displaying your capabilities on various different types of aspects or types of work, however... I'd suggest doing a reel that demonstrates the type of work you're happiest doing.

That all depends if you're aiming for a specific thing, or want to try doing whatever work you can get your hands on. In the beginning, you might want to stick with the types of work you do best. As you do this, it will bring in more work that you are happy and comfortable doing so there's less chance you find a project that might be too challenging for you at the moment.

Challenging and different types of projects will come your way regardless of how specific your reel is. So you'll get a chance to curate those skills anyways. Then when you're more comfortable and have produced a body of work that does justice to your currently lesser developed skills you can add those to your reels as well.